# How can I merge two partitions into one?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

I'm using Dell Inspiron 3543 (came with 1TB HDD) running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Recently, I upgraded my laptop with 240GB SSD and installed my 1TB HDD mounted on the caddy.

I removed the caddy and did fresh install again on the SSD to take advantage of it. After the fresh installation, I inserted the caddy and deleted my previous OS from the HDD. I even deleted the Swap partition and formated the OS partition using Gparted(using live session).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I have got 3 partitions here (Extended patition & two file system partitions). I want merge the extended partition & the one with 215GB. I tried formatting and deleting those two partitions, so as to create a new partition with all the free space. But Gparted is not allowing to merge this way(I'm guessing that's because one is extended partition and the other is file system partition)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: These are two different issues and you should split them up into two separate questions to make it easier for people to respond.

Comment: Is there anything on p5 and p3? Why is p4 NTFS? Is your computer UEFI?

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode. That system is new enough that you should be using UEFI with gpt partitioned drives. And with gpt, you do not have the extended partition which is just a container for logical partitions, not a partition per se. Either way you cannot merge partitions. You have to backup data on one or other, delete partition, then expand remaining & restore data from backup.

Comment: @heynnema No. p5 and p3 are empty. I have backed the files on to p4. I think mine isn't a UEFI computer. I ran
 'ls /sys/firmware/efi'
and this is what I got.
'ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory'
I think this means it is not?!

Comment: @oldfred I haven't installed UEFI boot mode. I have tried deleting the p5 & p3 seperately/individually in combinations, but they provide seperate unallocated space; which stops me from expanding! My last resort would be to transfer the entire data on to someone's external HDD and wipe the entire HDD and make new partition table with gparted.

Comment: @heynnema I had windows previously. So it is NTFS. Even p3 used to be NTFS, I formatted it to ext4 yesterday thinking that might help me to merge p3 & p5.

Comment: You only have /sys/firmware/efi if you have booted in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: This doesn't look too complicated... however, I need to see 2 more screenshots... the `Disks` app looking at your /dev/sda 240G SSD, and `gparted` app looking at your /dev/sdb 1T HD. You DON'T have Windows installed, correct?

Comment: @heynnema No. I completely switched to Ubuntu in April. I'll add those screenshots to my question.

Comment: If you think so, please accept one of the answers as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark  and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the problem is solved and it may help others.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. A couple more things before I write an answer for you. Partitions /dev/sdb5 and /dev/sdb3 are currently empty, correct? What is your intention with the data that you've put into /dev/sdb4, as it's very full. Lastly, please edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema Thank  you for your time and helping me out :) user68186 answer solved the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how to delete logical partitions inside the extended partition. Since you have Ubuntu installed in the SSD (`/dev/sda`) you can boot from the SSD and do all the deleting of partitions in /dev/sdb`. There is no need to boot from the live USB.

## Step 1:  Make sure the partitions `/dev/sdb5`, and `/dev/sdb3` are not mounted.

You can unmount the partitions using Gparted.

## Step 2: Delete `/dev/sdb5` first

Since this logical partition resides inside the extended partition, you can't do anything to the extended partition, `/dev/sdb1`, if the extended partition is not empty. Therefore the `/dev/sdb5` must be deleted first.

Using Gparted, select the logical partition `/dev/sdb5` and then delete it. Press the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button on the top part of Gparted to actually do the work.

## Step 3: Delete `/dev/sdb1` second

Now that the logical partition is gone, you can get rid of the extended partition. You don't need it in this setup.

Within Gparted select the `/dev/sdb1` the extended partition. Delete this partition. Press the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button on the top part of Gparted to actually do the work.

## Step 4: Delete `/dev/sdb3` third

By now you should have got the hang of how to do it. Remember to **Apply**.

## Step 5: Create a new primary partition in the empty space

Now you have a big empty space in front of the `/dev/sdb4`. Use all this space to create another primary partition.

Since you don't have Windows any more, format this new primary partition as `ext4`.

Optionally add an entry in the file `/etc/fstab` so that the partition mounts at the boot time at a mount-point of your choice.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Extended partition is a kind of container for other partitions. The following procedure should work, if I am not mistaken.

Delete the following partitions:

- /dev/sdb5
- /dev/sdb3

And than enlarge extended partition and create a new one inside filling-up all the space inside extended partiton.

GParted is perfect tool for this.

Comment: This doesn't work. I had tried before. It still keeps the sdb1 which stops me from merging them. They remain seperate unallocated space. What I did is seperately delete sdb5; sdb1 and then sdb3. Then create a new partition with all the unallocated space. Anyways now things have been solved :)

Comment: What messages did you get when you're trying to ENLARGE sdb1 to the right to fill all unallocated space?